# Upload Previously Uploaded App To New App Store Account

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I have an application for a client uploaded to my own apple store account. After several years, he want it to be uploaded to his own store account. Since the app has push notification feature in it, I can't just transfer the ownership to him. Can I upload the same Application Name as before (I will have to delete the old one, of course) without any complication? I don't want to delete the app now without knowing that I can reupload the app under new store account with **the exact same application name**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer apps between account with the new option inside itunesConnect.

In this link you can get more information.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Also, if you delete the app this will happen (according apple documentation):

***Important:***  *If you delete your app, you can’t restore it. The SKU or **app name can’t be reused in the same organization**. If you’ve uploaded a build or set up this app for the iAd App Network, your bundle ID can’t be reused.*

So the app name must be released and you can reused in another organization (according Apple documentation).